# how to run solr/example using Ubuntu's pre-installed solr-common and solr-jetty

Tags: ubuntu, solr, jetty

Brief: 
I haven't found how to run the solr tutorial/example in
a system that already had solr & jetty installed.  What example 
config files would I need to modify to make them point to the Ubuntu
packages?

Details:
I'm given an Ubuntu host with solr-common and solr-jetty already installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep solr
ii  solr-common       1.4.1+dfsg1-2ubun enterprise search server based on Lucene - common 
ii  solr-jetty        1.4.1+dfsg1-2ubun enterprise search server based on Lucene - Jetty i
```

However, no one is using them yet for anything (i.e. I can upgrade, uninstall,
config however I want, etc.).

openjdk-7-jre-headless is also installed.

I'm new with solr, jetty, and java in general and don't know much
about where config files reside, which servers end-up running etc., but
I found several dirs/files that must have been created during
solr-common and solr-jetty's installation:

```
/etc/init.d/jetty
/etc/jetty/(jetty.conf, jetty-xinetd.xml, ...)
/etc/solr/web.xml
         /conf/(schema.xml, ...)
```

I'm currently reading the solr tutorial; downloaded a solr release, untarred
it and am about to launch Jetty via the solr/example:

user:/usr/local/src/apache-solr-3.5.0/example$ java -jar start.jar

However before doing so I'm wondering if I shouldn't be running the
tutorial with the solr + jetty packages that were already installed in
my system.  After all, those will be the ones that I'll be using once
I get past the tutorial.

Also, will running the solr/example modify in any way the setup that
was created via the solr-common and solr-jetty's packages?

Should I just unistall solr-common and solr-jetty and use the
downloaded solr release (not preferred; this feels like giving-up 
because of not knowing what's going on).

I haven't found anywhere how to run the solr tutorial/example in
a system that already had solr & jetty installed.  What example 
config files would I need to modify to make them point to the Ubuntu
packages?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I think you would have more control downloading the solr release. In fact, I don't get what's the reason for using a system package when you just have to extract a zip file.
Anyway, I guess you don't need the solr-jetty package to run the example because it already includes an executable jar that runs an embedded solr through jetty. You're on the right track if you're running this command:

```
user:/usr/local/src/apache-solr-3.5.0/example$ java -jar start.jar
```

This way you are using the solr-common package but not the solr-jetty package, I suppose.

Comment: thanks for your comment; if i ran "java -jar start.jar" from the solr release's example/ dir, wouldn't start.jar be pointing to the solr and jetty files that also reside under the example dir (i.e. solr-common would not be used)?

Comment: Yes, it would run the solr and jetty files under the example. It uses solr-common but I don't think this way you're using the solr-jetty package. Let me know if I misunderstood your comment. Is there something unclear in my answer?